# why do I get DLLnotFoundException with PCLCypto on Linux/mono

Tags: c#, mono, pcl-crypto

I have a C# application that works on Windows, but when I try to run this on Linux using Mono I get this error:

> System.DllNotFoundException: NCrypt
>
> at (wrapper managed-to-native) PInvoke.NCrypt.NCryptOpenStorageProvider(PInvoke.NCrypt/SafeProviderHandle&,string,PInvoke.NCrypt/NCryptOpenStorageProviderFlags)
>
> at PInvoke.NCrypt.NCryptOpenStorageProvider (System.String providerName, PInvoke.NCrypt+NCryptOpenStorageProviderFlags flags) [0x00000]
>
> at PCLCrypto.NCryptAsymmetricKeyProviderBase.ImportPublicKey (System.Byte[] keyBlob, PCLCrypto.CryptographicPublicKeyBlobType blobType)

This is called via:

```
var rsa = WinRTCrypto.AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(AsymmetricAlgorithm.RsaPkcs1);
```

How do I fix?

Answer (score 2):

This library, or at least the specific API you are using, appears to be using platform invoke to use Windows-specific libraries that are part of the operating system (CNG's ncrypt.dll). It does not appear it will work on non-Windows platforms.

You should use an alternative library that supports the cryptographic functions you are trying to use on the platform required.

Comment: that's what I thought too, but the library is the Nuget package PCLCypto, which appears to be able to target .NetPortable and .NetStandard as well as MonoAndroid, so I would have thought it should work?

Comment: @mcmillab It's entirely possible to write a .NET "Standard" library to use p/invoke that does not work on all platforms. I suspect this is multiplatform insomuch that it would work on Windows Phone and other Windows-like platforms.

Comment: thanks, understood. I'm not very familiar with PCLCrypto, but it seems to be designed specifically for cross-platform implementation of RSA. I would have thought that includes Mono? Does anyone have experience here?

Comment: It will run on Mono, but only on Windows as windows has the necessary CNG library. It appears you are using a Windows specific API. Can you edit your question to include the code that is generating that stack trace?

Comment: done, and yes sorry I meant mono on Linux rather than windows